# InitializeCulture() on every single page necessary?

Tags: .net-4.0, localization, asp.net-4.0, globalization

I have a web forms site that needs to be localized. I mean, it is localized, I just need to set the right language according to the domain. Something like:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    var i = Request.Url.Host.ToLower();
    var domain = i.Substring(i.Length - 2, 2);
    if (domain == "se")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("sv-SE");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            CultureInfo("sv-SE");
    }
    else if (domain == "dk")
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new
            CultureInfo("da-DK");
    }
}
```

**My first question is: Do I really have to call `InitializeCulture()` on every single page for the right resources the be loaded?**

Second question. I also have some global resources. If yes to first question, will they be set correctly as well?

Ps. `uiCulture="auto"` and `enableClientBasedCulture="true"` in webconfig will not be sufficient (long story).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. What you are doing complies with the [Microsoft-recommended method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).
And since your example determines what language to use based on the URL, then each page request may require a different language, so you just couldn't avoid doing this for each individual page.

As per your second question, yes, all resource loading depends on `CurrentCulture`. So both local and global resources will be affected by your culture initialization.

Answer (score 2):

If the language in the application does not differ on a page to page basis then it make sense to reuse the code as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12038641/353241).
Or better still use http module explained [here](http://typesafe.be/2006/01/27/a-better-alternative-to-initializeculture/).

Comment: Interesting. Will look into it!