# masterpage initializeculture no suitable method found to override error?

Tags: c#, calendar

I'm trying to develop a MultiLanguage web site using ASP.NET with C#
My problem is: I want to make my MasterPage support switching among languages, but when i put the "InitializeCulture()" inside the masterpage.cs, I got this error.

this is my code:

```
public partial class BasicMasterPage : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Day.IsToday)
    {
        e.Cell.Style.Add("background-color", "#3556bf");
        e.Cell.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
    }
}
Dictionary<string, System.Globalization.Calendar> Calendars =
    new Dictionary<string, System.Globalization.Calendar>()
    {
        {"GregorianCalendar", new GregorianCalendar()},
        {"HebrewCalendar", new HebrewCalendar()},
        {"HijriCalendar", new HijriCalendar()},
        {"JapaneseCalendar", new JapaneseCalendar()},
        {"JulianCalendar", new JulianCalendar()},
        {"KoreanCalendar", new KoreanCalendar()},
        {"TaiwanCalendar", new TaiwanCalendar()},
        {"ThaiBuddhistCalendar", new ThaiBuddhistCalendar ()}
    };

protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.Form["LocaleChoice"] != null)
    {
        string selected = Request.Form["LocaleChoice"];
        string[] calendarSetting = selected.Split('|');
        string selectedLanguage = calendarSetting[0];

        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);

        if (calendarSetting.Length > 1)
        {
            string selectedCalendar = calendarSetting[1];
            var cal = culture.Calendar;
            if (Calendars.TryGetValue(selectedCalendar, out cal))
                culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = cal;
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
}
```

How can I create a Base class?

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this, so I can't give you a solution, but I can tell you that method `InitializeCulture()` exists only on the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class, not the [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage) class, and that's why you get that error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The method `InitializeCulture()` exists only on the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class, not the [MasterPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.masterpage) class, and that's why you get that error.

To fix this, you could create a `BasePage` that all your specific pages inherit:

1. Create a new Class (not Webform), call it `BasePage`, or whatever you want.
2. Make it inherit [System.Web.UI.Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx).
3. Make all your other pages inherit the `BasePage`.

Here's an example:

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        //Do the logic you want for all pages that inherit the BasePage.
    }
}
```

And the specific pages should look something like this:

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage //Instead of it System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Your logic.
    }

    //Your logic.
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly without causing any errors. 
But the working of the calendar has stopped; whenever I select a type of calendar from comboBox it just never appear it. why?

Comment: @Nuha_IT I would suggest asking a new question with the new specific problem

Comment: @AskeB. so you are saying make the master page inherit the `BasePage` too? Because it inherits `System.Web.UI.MasterPage` by default? All other page do localize perfectly its only `MasterPage` that was the problem of the `OP` in the first place

Comment: @jaminator No, the master page shouldn't inherit the `BasePage`, since the `BasePage` is a `System.Web.UI.Page` and not a `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`. This solution is a way to create functionality for several `Page`s. What the OP wanted was to support changing languages on all sites by calling `initializeCulture()`. Since that method is defined on the `Page` class (the `MasterPage` has no equivalent, to my knowledge), I defined a `Page`-wrapper class that makes it possible to do the same feature for several pages. Basic OOD.

Comment: For master page localiztion second answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147367/localizing-strings-in-master-pages-of-asp-net-mvc-application works perfectly

Comment: @jaminator Ordering of answers won't be persistent. If you want to share a specific answer, you can click the share button on an answer to get the link.

Answer (score 9):

**There is an alternate solution that DOES NOT require you to create a BasePage.**

The problem with 'Culture' is that it gets set very very early on the page life cycle, so the `Page.InitializeCulture` event is one of the early events on the page (if not the only one) where we can hook up to change the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture`. But what if we do that even earlier, as soon as the Request begins on the server.

I do that on the `Application_BeginRequest` event on the `Global.asax` file which is called on every request.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["langCookie"];
  if (cookie != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
  {
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(cookie.Value);
  }
}
```

There I check for the existence of a cookie that holds the culture I want to use. If there's no cookie, then the default culture will be used.

To change the language on my application I just need a control that changes the cookie value client-side and then do a simple postback to the server. It doesn't matter if such control is on the Content Page or in the Master Page, it doesn't even need any code on the server-side, because all the processing is done on the method above, and the cookie gets set on the client-side even before the page is posted.

I've used a simple LinkButton (which is styled as a Mexican Flag), but you can use any other control that do a postback when clicked/changed.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnSpanish" runat="server" OnClientClick="SetLanguageCookie('es')" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="mxFlag" />
```

Right before this button posts back to the server, it runs the client-side click event which updates the cookie value I want to set, and voila!

I have the javascript code that sets the cookie at the Master Page head section:

```
function SetLanguageCookie(selectedLanguage) {
  var expDate = new Date();
  expDate.setDate(expDate.getDate() + 20); // Expiration 20 days from today
  document.cookie = "langCookie=" + selectedLanguage + "; expires=" + expDate.toUTCString() + "; path=/";
};
```

That's it!! The `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` gets changed and no `BasePage` class is needed nor overriding the `Page.InitializeCulture` method. There's even the side effect that the language selected is remembered on following visits since it's stored on a cookie.

If you want to use a `DropDownList` instead of a `LinkButton`, just make sure to set the `AutoPostBack="true"` and, since there is no `OnClientChanged` property for the `DropDownList`, you must hardcode the `onchange` attribute on the `DropDownList` and pass the selected value to the same javascript function.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlLanguage" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onchange="SetLanguageCookie(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <asp:ListItem Text="English" Value="en" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Español" Value="es" />
  <asp:ListItem Text="Français" Value="fr" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The `onchange` attribute is not part of the `DropDownList` properties, however, since the `DropDownList` is an analog control of the `<select>` control, the attribute is just placed 'as is' when the rendering happens, and it's rendered before the postback mechanism code. Here's the HTML rendered by the `DropDownList` above:

```
<select name="ctl00$cph1$ddlLanguage" onchange="SetLanguageCookie(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;ctl00$cph1$ddlLanguage\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="cph1_ddlLanguage">
  <option value="en">English</option>
  <option value="es">Español</option>
  <option value="fr">Français</option>
</select>
```

Hope someone finds this approach as useful as I do. :)

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you, you saved me a lot of hours trying to add a base page to my app. It is worth mentioning that instead of using javascript to edit the cookies, you can just add an action to any controller and edit the cookie with `Response.Cookies["language"].Value = `, and the global.asax file will grab the cookie right away