# Is Culture automatically applied in ASP.Net Webforms? ( not UICulture)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, date-formatting

I have a Webforms ASP.Net 4.5 app that has no culture or uiculture setting specified in web.config or elsewhere in code. I am concerned with dates being properly formatted for users from different countries i.e. Culture setting and not UICulture setting.

**Question**: If this ASP.Net app is used by users from Great Britain, Germany and USA, then would a date value be automatically formatted when displaying in asp:Label control, Or the developer needs to explicitly do this formatting?

The Label control is databound using databinding syntax of ASP.Net Webforms as in code snippets below.  For example, if Order Date is 10/4/2014  for a user in USA, then for a user in Great Britain or Germany it should display as 4/10/2014.

**Html**

```
<asp:Label id="lblOrderDate" runat="server" Text="<%# this.OrderDate %>"></asp:Label>
```

**Code-behind**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender,   EventArgs e)
{ 
   string orderId = this.txtOrderId.Text;
   Order order = DAL.GetOrder( orderId );
   this.OrderDate = order.OrderDate;
   this.Page.DataBind();
}

public DateTime OrderDate { get;set; }
```

**UPDATE 1**

I am not sure if I need to include following code in Page code-behind for setting culture, or it will be done automatically by ASP.Net? My guess is that ASP.Net would do this automatically, but not sure.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    string language = "en-us";

    //Detect User's Language.
    if (Request.UserLanguages != null)
    {
        //Set the Language.
        language = Request.UserLanguages[0];
    }

    //Set the Culture.
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(language);
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(language);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Culture can be set automatically by Asp.net based on what browser says. (which is what we get in Request.UserLanguages). If you did so `"<%# this.OrderDate %>"` will get formatted automatically based on that.

[Look at the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx)

> To have ASP.NET set the UI culture and culture to the first language
>   that is specified in the current browser settings, set UICulture and
>   Culture to auto. Alternatively, you can set this value to
>   auto:culture_info_name, where culture_info_name is a culture name. For
>   a list of culture names, see CultureInfo. You can make this setting
>   either in the @ Page directive or Web.config file.

```
<%@ Page Culture="auto" %>
```

Or globally for all pages.

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="auto"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But you cannot trust Request.UserLanguages. It is just a preference from browser. Its preferable to allow the user to make the choice by means of a listbox.

You can set it explicitly for each request programatically by overriding initializeculture call of the page.

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
{
    if (Request.Form["ListBox1"] != null)
    {
        String selectedLanguage = Request.Form["ListBox1"];
        Culture = selectedLanguage ;

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
            CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(selectedLanguage);

    }
    base.InitializeCulture();
}
```

Master pages don't have InitializeCulture() call. So if you want to do this for all pages then create a BasePage that inherits Page. And then allow all your pages to inherit from that page.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805897/masterpage-initializeculture-no-suitable-method-found-to-override-error)

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.

Comment: I think, it would be good if you can include that OrderDate would be automatically formatted if your approach is followed, since that was in my question.